# WiX/MSI: Where is the feature action value 5 documented?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I have created a WiX file over 2 years ago which contains a check for a feature action value of 5.

The value 5 should indicate reinstall/repair, but I can't find any WiX/msi documentation on it. The pages I've found go up to 4, like on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
  <!-- always install if feature will be installed/reinstalled local -->
  <Custom  Action="MyInstallAction" After="InstallFiles">
    <![CDATA[(&ca_feature=3) OR (&ca_feature=5)]]> <!--  <<< HERE  -->
  </Custom>

  <!-- remove if feature is going from local to absent -->
  <Custom  Action="MyUninstallAction" After="RemoveRegistryValues">
    <![CDATA[(&ca_feature=2) AND (!ca_feature=3)]]> 
  </Custom>
  <Custom  Action="UninstallUsbBusDriver" After="RemoveRegistryValues">
    <![CDATA[(&ca_feature=2) AND (!ca_feature=3)]]>
  </Custom>
```

I'm starting to wonder if the value 5 is ever used, but then again I find it hard to believe that I put it in there without a reason.

Comment: I suspect it may have the INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT value in maintenance mode when features can be added or removed, and feature action is set to default for a feature when nothing is going to happen to it. That's a guess of course, but setting it to any of the other values would be misleading as an indication of what is going to happen to the feature.

Comment: Question is old but I found this https://www.indigorose.com/webhelp/msifact/Program_Reference/LuaScript/Actions/MSI.GetFeatureState.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting. Here's the closest documentation I can find. Like you mention, on [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012.aspx#feature_and_component_state_values), the values `-1`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and ,`4` are documented. The related [Examples of Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368561.aspx) doesn't have any instances of 5.

The documentation for [MsiGetFeatureState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370117.aspx) has a list of constants from `msi.h`. If you have that around, it would be better to look there, but [a third party copy](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d9/d06/msi_8h_source.html#l00032) lists `INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT` with the value of 5. This value is corroborated on [KB 884468](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884468), but only shown with [MsiQueryProductState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370363.aspx); similarly the constant is mentioned on [MsiConfigureProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370070.aspx).

So, in short, it sounds likely that the value 5 is only valid in the context of a product, and is not valid in the context of a feature or component.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, it might well be the INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT. In the example `ca_feature1` is a sub-feature of my main application, but I do not show the feature tree.

Perhaps the real problem is that the install state is not set to local. This might be causing the issue I'm having with my setup, currently. If you have any info on that it would be very welcome, I'll try a bit longer myself before posting a new SO question for that :)

Answer (score 2):

There was a comment left on a Microsoft documentation page indicating that an INSTALLSTATE of 5 is "when the feature is about to be reinstalled/repaired".  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx